# React Native Call recording for Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, kotlin

Is it possible to recording the call from react native app? I want to record the outgoing call from React Native App in Android.

By using **React Native Call Detection** package. I am able to find outgoing and incoming call. But I am not able to find package for record call from React Native app.

Comment: "*Please provide any reference documentation or article.*" - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)